# How to triangulate points in 3d with triangles (not tetrahedrons) using CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal

Using CGAL, I have some points in R^3, they represent a 2-manifold that is closed and embedded in R^3. For the purpose of illustration, I have a S^2 sphere:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
{
    double theta = 2 * CGAL_PI * i / num_vertices;
    double phi = CGAL_PI * i / num_vertices;
    double x = std::sin(phi) * std::cos(theta);
    double y = std::sin(phi) * std::sin(theta);
    double z = std::cos(phi);
    points.emplace_back(x,y,z);
}
```

I would like to triangulate this sphere using CGAL and obtain a **triangle** mesh. It seems to me that Triangulation_3 generates tetrahedral meshes. I would like each facet to have 3 vertices, not 4. In the [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/index.html), it does seem that degenerate cases are supported, but I'm struggling to find how to properly use triangle connectivity.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong package. Go back to the list of packages, and look for those that talk about surface, mesh, reconstruction, things like that.

Comment: May be, this is what you want... Please see: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction/index.html#subsecExampleNoInputPlane

Comment: Is it sufficient to construct the tetrahedra and then take only the surface triangles?  (That is, are you happy to have the convex hull?)

Comment: See the tutorlal about surface reconstruction algorithms in CGAL:  In fact you should have a look at the surface reconstuction algorithms. To get started have a look at the [tutorial](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html).